# I am trying to send certain parameters upon change through a JS file to a React Component but can't seem to do so

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arduino, backend, mqtt

The JS code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Replace the following with your MQTT broker details
  const brokerUrl = 'ws://192.168.55.201:9001';

  // Subscribe to multiple topics
  const topics = [
    'sensor/BMP280/pressure',
    'sensor/BMP280/altitude',
    'sensor/DHT11/humidity',
    'sensor/DHT11/temperature',
    'sensor/MQ135/air_quality',
  ];

  const client = mqtt.connect(brokerUrl);

  client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Connected to MQTT broker');

    // Subscribe to each topic
    topics.forEach(topic => {
      client.subscribe(topic, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log(`Subscribed to ${topic}`);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  // Initialize sensor data with default values or retrieved values (if applicable)
  let pressureValue = 50;
  let altitudeValue = 0;
  let humidityValue = 0; // Adjust the default value here if necessary
  let temperatureValue = 0; // Adjust the default value here if necessary
  let airQualityValue = 0; // Adjust the default value here if necessary

  // Function to update sensor data and export it
  

  client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    console.log(`Received message on topic: ${topic}, message: ${message.toString()}`);
    updateSensorDataAndExport(topic, message);
  });
});
const handleSensorData = (data) => {
  console.log('Sensor data:', data);
}
const exportSensorData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const data = {
      pressureValue,
      altitudeValue,
      humidityValue,
      temperatureValue,
      airQualityValue,
    };
    resolve(data);
  });
};
const updateSensorDataAndExport = (topic, message) => {
  const value = message.toString();

  switch (topic) {
    case 'sensor/BMP280/pressure':
      pressureValue = value;
      break;
    case 'sensor/BMP280/altitude':
      altitudeValue = value;
      break;
    case 'sensor/DHT11/humidity':
      humidityValue = value;
      break;
    case 'sensor/DHT11/temperature':
      temperatureValue = value;
      break;
    case 'sensor/MQ135/air_quality':
      airQualityValue = value;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  // Export the updated sensor data using a dedicated function
  exportSensorData(handleSensorData);
};
export { updateSensorDataAndExport, exportSensorData };
```

The React Component -

```
import styles from "./RightBox.module.css";
import WelcomeBack from "./WelcomeBack";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Row1 from "./Row1";
import Row2 from "./Row2";
import LineGraph from "./LineGraph";
import { updateSensorDataAndExport, exportSensorData } from "../backendData.js";

const RightBox = () => {
  const [parameters, setParameters] = useState([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const newSensorData = await exportSensorData();
      const newParameters = [
        Number(newSensorData.pressureValue),
        Number(newSensorData.altitudeValue),
        Number(newSensorData.humidityValue),
        Number(newSensorData.temperatureValue),
        Number(newSensorData.airQualityValue),
      ];
      setParameters(newParameters);
    };
  
    const interval = setInterval(fetchData, 1000); // Adjust the interval based on your requirements
  
    // Cleanup interval on component unmount
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once after the initial render // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once after the initial render

  const handleIncrement = (i) => {
    const newParameters = parameters.map((p, index) => (i === index ? p + 10 : p));
    setParameters(newParameters);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.rightbox}>
      <WelcomeBack />
      <div className={styles.graph}>
        <LineGraph />
      </div>
      <Row1 Parameters={parameters} />
      <Row2 handleIncrement={handleIncrement} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default RightBox;
```

What changes can I make to the above code so that it exports the needed values from the JS file upon change in those values to the React Component written above. ......................................................................................................................................................................................